# Latex3 drivers question

Tags: expl3, compilation-error

I wrote a few packages almost a year ago and they used to work just fine, as far as I can remember. Today I decided to start getting back into LaTeX again, and I updated my Miktex installation and other packages. But when I revisited some of the utility packages I had written for myself, I found that one of them **no longer compiles, because the control sequence `\driver_box_use_scale:Nnn` is "not defined"**. (Or rather, it *is* defined [see below!] but that definition is not available to the compiler for whatever reason.)

A quick Google search for this CS (after determining that it was not one that I had defined myself) tells me that its definition can be found in `l3pdfmode.def`, generated from `l3drivers.dtx` "with options: 'package,pdfmode'", which is part of the "l3kernel bundle".

I see that in the document titled "The Latex 3 Interfaces" (`interface3.pdf`), it says about the additions to `l3box`:

> These functions require the LATEX3 native drivers: they do not work withthe LATEX 2εgraphicsdrivers!

In the document "The expl3 package and LaTeX programming" (`expl3.pdf`), there are a list of backend options that seem to be relevant, **but I never specified which backend when using the package before, and like I said, my document compiled just fine.**

**Do any of you know if there have been any changes made to the `expl3` package that might be causing this? Or if there might have been some special options I was passing to the compiler that I don't remember anymore?**

Comment: Driver-specific code no longer has public interfaces. Try with `\box_scale:Nnn` and then `\box_use:N`.

Comment: That's the catch when programming on top of expl3.  You have to keep up with the development.  It might become clearer once you realize that `expl` stands for experimental.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Do you think it might be possible to implement my own interface to it? I don't think I'll need to, if `\box_scale:Nnn` works similarly, but I'm just curious.

Comment: @HenriMenke Ah thank you. I did not notice what it stood for. Are there plans to have it move past the "experimental" stage?

Comment: @ksoo Yes, it should be possible. If you just want to mimick the behaviour of `\driver_box_use_scale:Nnn`, then something like `\box_new:N \l_ksoo_tmpa_box \cs_new_protected:Npn \ksoo_box_use_scale:Nnn #1#2#3 { \box_set_eq:NN \l_ksoo_tmpa_box #1 \box_scale:Nnn \l_ksoo_tmpa_box {#2} {#3} \box_use_drop:N \l_ksoo_tmpa_box }` should do the trick. Also, `expl` does stand for experimental, but that name is mostly legacy. The entire `l3kernel` is regarded as broadly stable nowadays. You just happened to pick a spot which was not very well defined in the past and got corrected.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you so much!